# add network speed information in status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

How can I show a piece of information (in my case the data transfer speed between device and the server) on the status bar of the device like below :

[image]

I am a newbie to android. All suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to suggest a solution maybe it will help !

1- get your transfer data (upload and download) stored in 2 Strings variables (if the values are not already strings you can use ".toString()" or ".valueof" it depends

2- now make a permanent notification containing the two strings and a couple of icons 
and this should help you :

-permamnet notif in notification bar : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing%28boolean%29

-for the icons : 
https://design.google.com/icons/